# Passing environment variables from powershell to MSYS2 bash

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, msys2

How can I set an environment variable in PowerShell such that it will be visible in a child MSYS2 bash process?  Here is a PowerShell session showing what I tried:

```
PS D:\msys64> $env:ABCD = "foo"
PS D:\msys64> usr\bin\bash -l -c "env | grep ABCD; echo Value: $ABCD"
ABCD=foo
Value:
```

As you can see, the environment variable is visible in the output of `env`, but it is not available as a bash shell variable, which means it won't really work.

The expected output of the command above would be:

```
ABCD=foo
Value: foo
```

What is the right way to pass environment variables to MSYS2?  Or how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Before bash you need to export ABCD: export ABCD

Comment: OK, in PowerShell, I tried "export ABCD: export ABCD" and similar commands, and I just get the error message "export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Powershell expanded $ABCD before invoking Bash.  The solution is to write the command like this, using a backtick as an escape character:

```
usr/bin/bash -l -c "env | grep ABCD; echo Value: `$ABCD"
```